# Will I be fined or arrested transferring through Finland with expired Schengen visa?

Tags: transit, chinese-citizens, finland

I'm a Chinese student studying in Sweden. My visa extension was rejected by the Swedish migration office, and because of this I will leave for China within a month. However, I had no idea about a potential transfer problem in Finland, as my visa has been expired for half a year.

Is there any possibility that I will be arrested while in the transfer in Helsinki?

Comment: You won't be arrested, but you might be fined.  However, if you have a document from the Swedish authorities with your refusal, saying that you must leave by a certain date, and you're leaving before that date, then you also should not be fined, because you are complying with the conditions imposed upon you by the authorities.

Comment: If you made an out-of-time application, then yes you will be vulnerable to fines and what have you. If you made an in-time application and your refusal gives you a removal date, they you'll be ok. You didn't include that information so your question is being marked as 'unclear'.

Answer (score 1):

When passing through passport control in Finland, simply Show the refusal letter.

Since it contains the date by which the Swedish Migration board has ordered you to Exit Schengen, you would not be treated as an overstayer even if your visa is expired

Comment: How about some references, or explanations? One line answers get flagged by teh system as low quality and often downvoted :/

Comment: OP would likely need to get the letter translated into English first.

Comment: No, Swedish is an official language in Finland, taught in schools and spoken by many Finns (by some even as a native language) so there's bound to be at least some Swedish-speaking staff on duty.