# Do I need a transit Visa in Helsinki?

Tags: visas, transit, airports, chinese-citizens, helsinki

I am a Chinese citizen and I will be travelling from Copenhagen to Beijing. However I have a layover in Helsinki and recently I have been rejected a student visa in Sweden (I am allowed to travel from Copenhagen). I got a letter from the Swedish Migration Office that I have 4 weeks to leave the country, which expires on the 1st of June. The layover is no more than 4 hours and I do not plan to leave the airport. 
Do I still need the transit visa in Finland?

Comment: Um, Helsinki is not in Sweden, it's in Finland. If it's legal for you to be in Copenhagen before you take the flight, then based on your story it should be no less legal for you to be in Helsinki during your layover. **However** if you're being told to leave Sweden, it's likely that you're not allowed to be present _anywhere_ in the Schengen area after the four weeks run out -- including Copenhagen and Helsinki. What _exactly_ did Migrationsverket write to you?

Comment: This appears to be the same question (and the same asker) as [Will I be fined or arrested transferring through Finland with expired Schengen visa?](http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/68955/will-i-be-fined-or-arrested-transferring-through-finland-with-expired-schengen-v).

Answer (score 1):

Copenhagen is in Denmark, and Helsinki in Finland. For border purposes, Denmark and Finland are actually **in the same "Country"**, called the Schengen Area (or Schengen for short). Therefore Copenhagen-Helsinki flights are practically domestic, so you only clear Immigration in Helsinki - that's when you exit Schengen.